# The method getMouseX() is undefined for the type Shooter

Tags: java, input, mouse

I've been using the HSA_UFA console and its not very common, but it is what I'm learning in school. I'm using Java and it gave me the error: "The method `getMouseX()` is undefined for the type Shooter"

```
public class Shooter {

static Console c = new Console(1000, 1000, 20, "S H O O T E R");

public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {

    int playerSpeed = 2;
    int playerX = 0;
    int playerY = 0;

    while(true) {

        //Drawing Frame 
        synchronized (c) {
            c.clear();
            c.fillRect(playerX, playerY, 15, 15);
        }

        //Schleeeeep
        Thread.sleep(10);

        //Player Controls
        if (c.isKeyDown('W')) {

            playerY -= playerSpeed;

        }

        if (c.isKeyDown('S')) {

            playerY += playerSpeed;
        }

        if (c.isKeyDown('A')) {

            playerX -= playerSpeed;

        }

        if (c.isKeyDown('D')) {

            playerX += playerSpeed;

        }

        if (c.getMouseButton(2)) {

            playerX = getMouseX();
            playerY = getMouseY();

        }

    }

}

}
```

Comment: `c.getMouseX()`? Who knows what that `Console` class is...

Answer (score 0):

You should use your console variable to access the `getMouseX()` because you're capturing the mouse location over the console window. And before calling this method `enableMouse()` and `enableMouseMotion()` can be called for surety.

```
public static void main(String arSgs[]) throws InterruptedException {

int playerSpeed = 2;
int playerX = 0;
int playerY = 0;

//enabling mouse capturing
c.enableMouse();
c.enableMouseMotion();

while(true) {

    /*
    * your code
    */

    if (c.getMouseButton(2)) {

        playerX = c.getMouseX();
        playerY = c.getMouseY();

    }
}
```

Comment: There is this big program which you can use for further reference 
[https://pastebin.com/aHaZNvbE](https://pastebin.com/aHaZNvbE)